# MongoDB retrieving data from inner classes. Using mongo template

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I just need a help to figure out how to fetch data from inner classes or list of classes using monogo db template and spring. for example if  i have a class having data

class **user**:

```
String id;
String userName;
String firstName;
String lastName;
ArrayList<Search> search;
```

class **Search**:

```
String key;
ArrayList<XYZ> XYZ;
```

class **XYZ**;

```
String id;
String name;
String data;
```

Now my problem is how to fetch data from XYZ class as its an inner class of User and search, what might be the query to fetch these data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Query searchUserQuery = new Query((Criteria.where("userName").is("rohit")));
searchUserQuery.addCriteria((Criteria.where("search.key").is("foo")));
searchUserQuery.addCriteria((Criteria.where("search.XYZ.id").is("10")));

This will return a result where userName is "rohit", search Key value is "foo" and XYZ class contains id =10.

Its working for me!!!.
```